# How to filter bluetooth tags through android apps

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

How to filter bluetooth tags in times of pairing with apps. For instance, "Tile" doesn't connect with tags other than their authorized tags. My question is, how do they recognize their authorized tags through apps?

Comment: Do you mean 'device names'?

Comment: In details, If I have lots of tag in my bluetooth range, I want to show only my company's tag in app. Other tags will not be shown in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to connect to an untrusted device, send a signal with an specific result expected, if it receives fine, then "trust" that device.

Then, on next loads, check the paired MAC address..

Something akin to:

```
private BluetoothDevice mDevice = null;
if (mDevice == null) {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Set<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                        .getBondedDevices();
                if (bluetoothDevices != null && bluetoothDevices.size() > 0) {
                    String bondedID = SharedPreferences.getInstance(
                            getApplicationContext()
                    ).getPairedAddress();
                    if (bondedID != null) {
                        for (final BluetoothDevice device : bluetoothDevices) {
                            if (device != null
                                    && device.getAddress().equals(bondedID)) {
                                mDevice = device;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Logger.v(TAG, "There are no Bluetooth Paired devices");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean sending a signal to a bluetooth tag, and in response if the app receives an expected result then trust the tag?

Comment: Yes, that can work (it is as I do), but other ways are also common, such as trusting only specific device names (by using `mDevice.getName()`), etc.

Comment: My thoughts are with security issue. If someone sells his own tags using my app, how would I prevent my app from trusting those tags.

Comment: Like my previous comment, you can use many different ways to "trust" a Bluetooth device. Common ways include the device name (and your tags would have that name), MAC ranges, handshakes, "heartbeats", etc. You can even use several ways at once.

Comment: This helps me a lot. Got the way to solve. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If your question is answered, check the `✓` sign on the left of the question. This helps the forum to mark it as answered (and does not need further interactions), and helps new users with similar questions to check on a way to solve the issue. Welcome to StackOverflow, if you need any help, post a new question.